# BackPropagation leading to same output values for each training example

Tags: java, neural-network, mnist, backpropagation

Hello I am learning how to make neural networks.  I am starting out with a very simple vanilla network in java that seems unable to learn. The network seems to tend towards outputting values close to 0(generally about 0.05 - 0.2). I think the error is with my backprogation. Here is the co:e for the network:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class CustomNeuralNetwork
{
    double[][] InputWeights;
    double[][][] HiddenWeights;
    double[][] OutputWeights;
    double[][] HiddenBias;
    double[] OutputBias;
    public CustomNeuralNetwork(int InputSize, int HiddenLayerSize, int HiddenLayers, int OutputSize){
        InputWeights = new double[HiddenLayerSize][InputSize];
        HiddenWeights = new double[HiddenLayers - 1][HiddenLayerSize][HiddenLayerSize];
        OutputWeights = new double[OutputSize][HiddenLayerSize];
        HiddenBias = new double[HiddenLayers][HiddenLayerSize];
        OutputBias = new double[OutputSize];
    }
    public static double[] Activation(double[] x){
        double[] Out = new double[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < Out.length; i++){
            Out[i] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x[i]));
        }
        return Out;
    }
    
    public static double[] ActivationPrime(double[] x){
        double[] Out = new double[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < Out.length; i++){
            double Activation = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x[i]));
            Out[i] = Activation * (1 - Activation);
        }
        return Out;
    }
    public void InitilizeNetwork(){
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < InputWeights.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < InputWeights[i].length; j++){
                InputWeights[i][j] = -1 + ( 2 * r.nextDouble());
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < HiddenWeights.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < HiddenWeights[i].length; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < HiddenWeights[i][j].length; k++){
                    HiddenWeights[i][j][k] = -1 + (2 * r.nextDouble());
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < OutputWeights.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < OutputWeights[i].length; j++){
                OutputWeights[i][j] = -1 + (2 * r.nextDouble());
            }
        }
        //Bias's don't need to be initilized since they start at 0
    }
    public static double[] multiply(double[][] matrix, double[] vector) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int columns = matrix[0].length;
        double[] result = new double[rows];

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
                sum += matrix[row][column]
                        * vector[column];
            }
            result[row] = sum;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static double[] Add(double[] a, double[] b){
        double[] Out = new double[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < Out.length; i++){
            Out[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        return Out;
    }
    public static double[] Subtract(double[] a, double[] b){
        double[] Out = new double[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < Out.length; i++){
            Out[i] = a[i] - b[i];
        }
        return Out;
    }
    public static double[] Mult(double[] a, double[] b){
        double[] Out = new double[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < Out.length; i++){
            Out[i] = a[i] * b[i];
        }
        return Out;
    }
    public Prediction Predict(double[] Inputs){
        Prediction Out = new Prediction();
        
        Out.Inputs = Inputs;
        Out.HiddenLayers = new double[HiddenWeights.length + 1][HiddenBias[0].length];
        double[] CurrentLayer = Activation(Add(multiply(InputWeights, Inputs), HiddenBias[HiddenBias.length - 1]));
        Out.HiddenLayers[Out.HiddenLayers.length - 1] = CurrentLayer;
        for(int i = HiddenWeights.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            CurrentLayer = Activation(Add(multiply(HiddenWeights[i], CurrentLayer), HiddenBias[i]));
            
            Out.HiddenLayers[i] = CurrentLayer;
        }
        Out.Outputs = Activation(Add(multiply(OutputWeights, CurrentLayer), OutputBias));


        return Out;
        
    }
    public Deltas BackPropagation(Prediction Out){
        //δ Important Greek letter 
        double[] δ = Mult((Subtract(Out.Expected, Out.Outputs)), ActivationPrime(Add(multiply(OutputWeights, Out.HiddenLayers[Out.HiddenLayers.length - 1]), OutputBias)));
        double[][] OutputWeightDeltas = new double[OutputWeights.length][OutputWeights[0].length];
        double[] OutputBiasDeltas = new double[OutputBias.length];
        double[][][] HiddenWeightDeltas = new double[HiddenWeights.length][HiddenWeights[0].length][HiddenWeights[0][0].length];
        double[][] HiddenBiasDeltas = new double[HiddenBias.length][HiddenBias[0].length];
        double[][] InputWeightsDeltas = new double[InputWeights.length][Out.HiddenLayers.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < OutputWeightDeltas.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < OutputWeightDeltas[i].length; j++){
                OutputWeightDeltas[i][j] = δ[i] * Out.HiddenLayers[Out.HiddenLayers.length - 1][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < OutputBiasDeltas.length; i++){
            OutputBiasDeltas[i] = δ[i];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < HiddenWeights.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                δ = Mult(ActivationPrime(Add(multiply(HiddenWeights[i], Out.HiddenLayers[i + 1]), HiddenBias[i + 1])), Influence(OutputWeights, δ));
            }
            else{
                δ = Mult(ActivationPrime(Add(multiply(HiddenWeights[i], Out.HiddenLayers[i + 1]), HiddenBias[i + 1])), Influence(HiddenWeights[i - 1], δ));
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < HiddenWeightDeltas[i].length; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < HiddenWeightDeltas[i][j].length; k++){
                    HiddenWeightDeltas[i][j][k] = δ[j] * Out.HiddenLayers[i][k];
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < HiddenBiasDeltas[i].length; j++){
                HiddenBiasDeltas[i][j] = δ[j];
            }
        }
        δ = Mult(ActivationPrime(Add(multiply(InputWeights, Out.Inputs), HiddenBias[HiddenBias.length - 1])), Influence(HiddenWeights[HiddenWeights.length - 1], δ));
        for(int i = 0; i < InputWeightsDeltas.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < InputWeightsDeltas[i].length; j++){
                InputWeightsDeltas[i][j] = δ[j] * Out.Inputs[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < HiddenBias[HiddenBias.length - 1].length; i++){
            HiddenBias[HiddenBias.length - 1][i] = δ[i];
        }
        double[] Cost = new double[Out.Expected.length];
        float y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Cost.length; i++){
            Cost[i] = (Out.Expected[i] - Out.Outputs[i]) * (Out.Expected[i] - Out.Outputs[i]); 
            y+= Cost[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Cost: " + y);
        Deltas x = new Deltas();
        x.HiddenBiasDeltas = HiddenBiasDeltas;
        x.HiddenWeightDeltas = HiddenWeightDeltas;
        x.InputWeightsDeltas = InputWeightsDeltas;
        x.OutputBiasDeltas = OutputBiasDeltas;
        x.OutputWeightDeltas = OutputWeightDeltas;
        return x;
        
    }
    
    public static double[] Influence(double[][] Weights, double[] δ){
        double[] Out = new double[Weights[0].length];
        for(int n = 0; n < Out.length; n++){
            for(int m = 0; m < Weights.length; m++){
                Out[n] += δ[m] * Weights[m][n];
            }
        
        }
        return Out;
    }   

}
```

and the code that calls this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DigitRecognizer
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CustomNeuralNetwork network = new CustomNeuralNetwork(784, 36, 3, 10);
        double[][] TrainingData = new double[60000][784];
        double[][] ExpectedOutputs = new double[60000][10];
        double LearningRate = 0.001;
        int Epoches = 50000;
        try { 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("mnist_train.csv"));
            
            for(int i = 0; scan.hasNext(); i++){
                String[] Image = scan.next().split(",");
                if(Image[0].equals("0")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("1")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("2")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("3")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("4")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("5")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("6")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("7")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
                }
                else if(Image[0].equals("8")){
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
                }
                else{
                    ExpectedOutputs[i] = new double[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < 784; j++){
                    
                    TrainingData[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(Image[j+1])/1000.0 ;
                    
                }
               
                
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Can't find File");}
        network.InitilizeNetwork();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < Epoches; i++){
            Deltas[] BackProp = new Deltas[32];
            for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
                int Example = rand.nextInt(0, 60000);

                Prediction guess = network.Predict(TrainingData[Example]);
                guess.Expected = ExpectedOutputs[Example];
                BackProp[j] = network.BackPropagation(guess);
                
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
                Deltas x = BackProp[j];
                for(int k = 0; k < x.HiddenBiasDeltas.length; k++){
                    for(int l = 0; l < x.HiddenBiasDeltas[k].length; l++){
                        network.HiddenBias[k][l] += (LearningRate * (1.0/32.0) *x.HiddenBiasDeltas[k][l]);
                    }
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < x.HiddenWeightDeltas.length; k++){
                    for(int l = 0; l < x.HiddenWeightDeltas[k].length; l++){
                        for(int m = 0; m < x.HiddenWeightDeltas[k][l].length; m++){
                            network.HiddenWeights[k][l][m] += (LearningRate * (1.0/32.0) * x.HiddenWeightDeltas[k][l][m]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < x.InputWeightsDeltas.length; k++){
                    for(int l = 0; l < x.InputWeightsDeltas[k].length; l++){
                        network.InputWeights[k][l] += (LearningRate * (1.0/32.0) * x.InputWeightsDeltas[k][l]);
                    }
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < x.OutputBiasDeltas.length; k++){
                    network.OutputBias[k] += (LearningRate * (1.0/32.0) * x.OutputBiasDeltas[k]);
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < x.OutputWeightDeltas.length; k++){
                    for(int l = 0; l < x.OutputWeightDeltas[k].length; l++){
                        network.OutputWeights[k][l] += (LearningRate * (1.0/32.0) * x.OutputWeightDeltas[k][l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Prediction and deltas are simple data classes with only the variables shown)
The code is trying to recognize digits with the MNIST data set.